# Unity Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте!

В *Unity* я новичок. Делаю 2Д игру. При попытке отследить куда происходить клик на "игровом поле" получил такую ошибку в консоли:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Select.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Select.cs:23)

Метод, в котором это происходит:

```
void Update() {    
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100)) {
        Debug.Log ("Hit something!");
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("No Hit something!");
    }
}
```

23 строка:

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

Можете наставить меня на путь истинный? И буду благодарен, если посоветуете литературу для развития в скриптинге на *Unity*.

Comment: На официальном сайте Unity очень много информации по разработке в этой среде, в том числе и программирование. Возможно вы видели не все разделы? На литературу конкретно по Unity, где было бы написано что-то о разработке, принципиально лучшую чем на официальном сайте не натыкался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы изменили тег камеры. Предположу, что изменили его на `Select`. Меж тем, как `Camera.main` ищет камеру именно с тегом `MainCamera`.

То есть, как решение: вам нужно либо сменить тег обратно, на нужный, либо искать камеру уже по тегу:

```
Camera cam = GameObject.FindWithTag("YOUR_TAG").GetComponent<Camera>();
Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

или через `Find`, как обычный gameObject (работает медленнее):

```
GameObject.Find("CAMERA_NAME").camera
Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

или еще каким-либо способом, которым можно найти нужный объект.

P.S. Обычно `Ray` и `MousePosition` используют, когда нажали на клавишу мышки, то есть обычно пишут что-то типа:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray)) {
        // do smth
    }
}
```

Это на случай, **если** вдруг вы запланировали **именно такую** логику. Чтоб в холостую луч не пускать.

Comment: Мне нужно с помощью луча выделять объекты(изменять значение булевой переменной). Подскажите на какой объект нужно вешать скрипт?

Comment: @Giggs это всё зависит.....может  у вас есть игрок и он стреляет в кого из ружья, тогда на него и луч должен исходить из ружья. А может просто у вас просто камера и движущиеся мобы и вы тыкаете мышкой, тогда можно и на камеру. Тут всё упирается в логику, в то, что есть и что планиурется

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Возникла еще одна проблема.
`if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
   if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
    Ray selectRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (selectRay)) {
     Debug.Log (this.gameObject.tag);
    }
   }
  }`     в консоль выводит, что отмечена камера а не другой объект

Comment: @Giggs делайте `raycast` как вы делали в своем примере `Physics.Raycast(selectRay, out hit, 100)`  ... и потом берите тег из `hit.gameObject.tag`